# Como selecionar com regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu estou tentando formatar texto do seguinte tipo

```
123,345,234   //tem que ficar 123345,234
abc,def,adf   //tem que ficar abcdef,adf
123,345,678,abc,qualquer,coisa    //tem que ficar 123345678abcqualquer,coisa
```

Eu preciso retirar todas as virgula, menos a ultima, como eu faço isso com expressão regular em javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex `/,(?=[^,]*,)/g` e o método `replace`:

```js
var a = "123,345,234";   //tem que ficar 123345,234
var b = "abc,def,adf";   //tem que ficar abcdef,adf
var c = "123,345,678,abc,qualquer,coisa";    //tem que ficar 123345678abcqualquer,coisa

var a2 = a.replace(/,(?=[^,]*,)/g, "");
var b2 = b.replace(/,(?=[^,]*,)/g, "");
var c2 = c.replace(/,(?=[^,]*,)/g, "");

document.write(a2 + "<br/>");
document.write(b2 + "<br/>");
document.write(c2);
```

Comment: É isso mesmo que preciso!! pode me explicar o o que significa a parte (?= )   ?

Comment: Essa parte indica uma condição para que a vírgula seja considerada. A condição que eu usei é que deve haver uma outra vírgula após o termo em questão. Portanto, só são consideradas na substituição, virgulas que depois dela apareça outra vírgula.

Comment: Eu uso o [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/#javascript) para testar regexes, dá uma olhada que vale a pena.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! aprendi!

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer isso só com javascript:

```
function arranjar(str){
    var partes = str.split(',');
    var ultima = partes.pop();
    return [partes.join(''), ultima].join(',');
}
arranjar('123,345,678,abc,qualquer,coisa') // dá "123345678abcqualquer,coisa"
```

Para fazer isso com regex não é mais simples. Mas um exemplo seria assim:

```
function arranjarComRegex(str){
    var partes = str.match(/(.*),(.*)/);
    var string = partes[1].replace(/,/g, '');
    return string + ',' + partes[2];
}
```

Neste caso a regex `(.*),(.*)` captura dois grupos. No primeiro captura `'123,345,678,abc,qualquer'` onde precisa remover as virgulas com `.replace(/,/g, '')` e o segundo grupo de captura apanha a ultima palavra, que depois precisa juntar de volta na string com `string + ',' + partes[2]`.

Comment: é que na verdade, queria mais saber em como fazer isso com regex

Comment: @Lai32290 ok, vou juntar um exemplo com regex.